# Validation Errors , Even all the fields filled through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validationerror

Code :
document.getElementById("input-4").value = "Dutta"

Screenshots:

[image: Inspect code for Last name]

[image: Validation error when clicks on save button]

Description :

I got the validation errors when we click on save button(attached screenshot).

**Last Name** is the input type and type is  text.

using the below line code to display the value.

**document.getElementById("input-4").value = "Dutta"**
but value is displaying , validation is not satisfying.

Highly Appreciated if anyone helps.

I tried with

document.getElementById("input-4").value = "Dutta"
document.getElementById("input-4").defaultValue = "Dutta"
but not working.

While we inspect the code once we enter manually then value is assigned to attribute **value = "Dutta"**
except that value is not assigning to given attribute in input tag.

Comment: the `label` has `required` attribute. maybe that is causing the problems? either way, try posting a textual representation of the code, or even better, a reproducible example

Comment: Hi, are you accessing the input element "input-4" for last name on purpose? In your screenshot lastName has the id "input-6".

Comment: Just i kept one feild example.
input-4 is fitst name and input-6 is last Name

Comment: I have tried with aria-required=flase and removed remove from label but still error is there.
 i am observing that when Manually enter something then value attribute getting entered value.
once we are using  then value is not assigning to value attribute